# Implement SOAP 1.1 in php

Tags: php, soap

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response

```
POST /DEMOWebServices2.8/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.efxnow.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://api.efxnow.com/webservices2.3/DealRequestAtBest"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Authenticator xmlns="https://api.efxnow.com/webservices2.3">
      <ApplicationName>string</ApplicationName>
      <IPAddress>string</IPAddress>
      <UserID>string</UserID>
      <MachineName>string</MachineName>
    </Authenticator>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <DealRequestAtBest xmlns="https://api.efxnow.com/webservices2.3">
      <UserID>string</UserID>
      <PWD>string</PWD>
      <Pair>string</Pair>
    </DealRequestAtBest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <DealRequestAtBestResponse xmlns="https://api.efxnow.com/webservices2.3">
      <DealRequestAtBestResult>
        <Success>boolean</Success>
        <ErrorDescription>string</ErrorDescription>
        <ErrorNumber>int</ErrorNumber>
        <Confirmation>string</Confirmation>
        <ConfirmationNumber>string</ConfirmationNumber>
        <Rate>double</Rate>
      </DealRequestAtBestResult>
    </DealRequestAtBestResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i want to know how to make the request and how to handle response if this had to be done in php. i read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) but i can't figure out how would `__setSoapHeaders()` and `__call()` be implemented in my case. thanks in advance.

Comment: look on tutorials  http://devzone.zend.com/article/689

Answer (score 1):

There's a SOAP library for PHP, but for a simple exchange you might consider building XML request body as a string and the dispatch it using the curl library function. It's a much more low-level network api, which I at least find easier to use. Note that PHP needs to be compiled --with-curl[=DIR].

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    if ((bool)$proxy) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Pragma:','Cache-Control:'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }
    // Apply the XML to our curl call
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data); 

    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```